# How to update MDB Admin Template assets in asp mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript, mdbootstrap

I have successfully integrated MDB Angular Dashboard template in ASP MVC application using this article https://www.mithunvp.com/angular-asp-net-mvc-5-angular-cli-visual-studio-2017/, but now the problem is that the Angular application is now not able to find the assets,

```
<img src="../../../../assets/img/angular-mdb.png" alt="Error 404" class="img-fluid" width="200px" height="20px">
```

for example the assets linked in the angular application are four levels above the component directory but now I changed the output directory in angular.json and tsconfig.json, now the output is in Scripts/libs/assets, so how do I update the path for my assets? TIA

Comment: ~/Scripts/libs/assets/img/... might be what you are looking for.

Comment: @Bosco thanks for the suggestion I was able to update the paths with ../../../Scripts/assets/img/angular-mdb.png, But now I have fonts from fontawesome in the same Scripts folder and in my html when ever I am using fa class the fonts are being searched in that component i.e. http://localhost:61143/Home/Contact/dashboards/fa-solid-900.woff2 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) where Home is my controller Contact is my action and dashboards is the folder for my dashboard component, any idea how to solve this?